# Can I daisy-chain two monitors with only one DisplayPort input a Razer Thunderbolt 4 dock?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c, thunderbolt, daisychaining

I have a 13" M1 MacBook Pro from 2020 (model `MJ123LL/A`). It has two Thunderbolt 3 ports on it.

I also have a Razer Thunderbolt 4 dock (with 1 upstream T4 and 3 downstream T4 ports, as well as some USB-A ports), and two HP 24mh monitors (model 7XM23AA).

The monitors each have:

- 1 DisplayPort 1.2 port
- 1 HDMI 1.4 port
- 1 VGA port

I'm new to the multi-monitor setup idea, but my goal is to be able to close and vertically dock my MacBook Pro when I'm in my office and tuck it out of the way, and use a full desktop setup with two monitors.

So far, my research seems to indicate that it is not possible with this setup to power two monitors, as I would need a DisplayPort "out" on at least one of the monitors. What I am wondering is if I can still accomplish this in a different way without spending a ton of money or needing to replace one or both monitors.

One example, but I don't know enough about how this works, is maybe splitting the signal from the DP port on the first monitor, and running that to the second? Is there an adapter that could do that? Or am I not taking advantage of all the capabilities on my dock?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer since I did figure out a solution that works for me. I hope this will help someone else.

Using the hardware above, I found a nifty little tool from SonnetTech: https://www.sonnettech.com/product/m1-mac-dual-displayport-adapter/overview.html

I ordered two male-male DisplayPort cords (the Ivanky ones on Amazon feel reasonably high quality) and was able to plug them into my laptop.

You *must* download and install the DisplayLink software from Synaptics in order to use the DisplayLink splitter, but it does exactly what it promises: it splits the connection to two monitors from one cable.

A nice bonus, I was able to plug it into the aforementioned Razer dock, so I I am still able to plug in only one Thunderbolt cable into my Mac when I wish to dock it.

Hope this helps you!